# Create a defaultdict with dictionaries as default entries by the use of a factory function

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict

I want a Python 3 defaultdict that has a dictionary as entries.
It is supposed to look like that:

```
my_dict[first_index] -> {second_index_1: value_1, second_index_2: value_2}
```

How to create a defaultdict is outlined in the docs:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Example for a defaultdict with default-type *int*

```
d = defaultdict(int)

for k in s:

    d[k] += 1
```

More complex entries are created via a factory function (the first argument of *defaultdict* has to be callable):

```
def constant_factory(value):

    return lambda: value

d = defaultdict(constant_factory('<missing>'))
```

The problem is that the constant_factory function returns always the identical dict when using it like above:

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return lambda: value

my_dict = defaultdict(constant_factory({"second_index_1":None,"second_index_2":None}))

my_dict["first_index_1"]["second_index_1"] = "value_1"
```

yields:

```
my_dict["first_index_1"]["second_index_1"] -> "value_1"
```

as expected.

Now doing

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return lambda: value

my_dict = defaultdict(constant_factory({"second_index_1":None,"second_index_2":None}))

my_dict["first_index_1"]["second_index_1"] = "value_1"
my_dict["first_index_2"]["second_index_1"] = "value_2"
```

yields:

```
my_dict["first_index_1"]["second_index_1"] -> "value_2"
```

This means that by accessing the second entry in the dict, we modified the first one by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the factory function, which only creates one instance:

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return lambda: value
```

The this can be avoided by using

```
def constant_factory(value):
    return lambda: value.copy()
```

Copying the dict creates a different instance every time.